# Modem stopped working on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, internet, modem

I was using MTS Mblaze Modem for ~9 days on Ubuntu 12.10. It was working fine. It stopped working all of a sudden. It works fine on Windows.
rfkill list shows that nothing is blocked.
Is there something else I need to check so that the question is more clear?
Another detail, in case it helps:
Till yesterday, when I clicked 'On' in the Mobile Broadband option, I would get a
notification 'You are now registered on CDMA..'. I don't get that notification anymore.

**Output of lsusb:**

> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching
>   Hub
>  Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate
>   Matching Hub
>  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0
>   root hub
>  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0
>   root hub
>  Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:e258 Suyin Corp.
>  Bus 002
>   Device 013: ID 19d2:fff1 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM

Can someone please help me?

Comment: does it detect the device? is it a detection problem or one of connection?

Comment: Its a connection problem.

Comment: do you have usb modeswitch installed? also what is the output of lsusb?

Comment: Yes, usb modeswitch is installed. I've added the lsusb details.

Comment: go through this [link](http://theopenhelp.com/2010/10/how-to-setup-tata-photon-plus-on-ubuntu.html), i know that it's not the same service provider, but it might just help.

Comment: The file mentioned does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, the following steps should get your connection working-

1. Install wvdial

> sudo apt-get install wvdial

2.Install usb-modeswitch and usb-modeswitch-data from Ubuntu Software Center

3.Edit /etc/wvdial.conf using-

> sudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf

4.Add the following lines to the file:

```
[Dialer mts]

Stupid Mode = 1

Inherits = Modem0

Password = mts

Username = internet@internet.mtsindia.in

Phone = #777 [Modem0]

Init1 = ATZ

SetVolume = 0

Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0

Baud = 115200

FlowControl = Hardware (CRTSCTS)

Dial Command = ATDT
```

5.Save the file, close and run the command-

> sudo wvdial mts

NOTE: if you get an error on this step, disconnect your device and re-connect it after a short period of time, say 30 seconds.

That's it, remember to keep the terminal where you entered the command active, do not close it. The next time you wish to login, simply run the last command, i.e. sudo wvdial mts.

---

If there are any errors in connection despite the above steps, do the following-

> sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf

Add (Update or edit, depending upon the situation) the following details-

nameserver 10.228.129.114

nameserver 10.228.129.113

Save it and reconnect the modem.

Comment: I don't know how, but it started working again, automatically.

Comment: XD, congratulations then!

Comment: IT didn't last long enough. :/

Comment: did you try the solution?